# browser proces running outisde of explorer.exe

Tags: windows, process

can anyone please explain why the browser process are not running under explorer.exe? If I look at chrome.exe, msedge.exe, they have the `Parent` value set to `non-existing process` and a IP value of the parent process that already exited.

[image: browser]

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter?

Browsers might use their initial process when you launch them to get things ready and then start its UI and their sandboxed renderer/scripting child processes and then exit the initial process. This will break the parent process tree.

You should never rely on Explorer.exe being the parent of anything.